# How to access the matched node's value inside nested for-loop in xsl/xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

This maybe a silly question, but I'm new to `xslt` 1.0. Suppose a have a xml file like this:

fruits.xml:

```
<shop>
    <fruits>
        <fruit>apple</fruit>
        <fruit>banana</fruit>
    </fruits>

    <weights>
        <weight>1</weight>
        <weight>2</weight>
        <weight>3</weight>
    </weights>
</shop>
```

Now, my fruits.xsl file is something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="weights-in-kg" select="shop/weights/weight"/>

    <xsl:template name="some-template-I-have">
        <!-- HERE-I-HAVE-TO-USE-NODE-VALUE-OF-ELEMENT-FROM-WHERE-I-CALLED-THIS-TEMPLATE -->
        <xsl:value-of select="."> <!-- this used to give the node's value, now it is returing for-loop element's value -->
        <!-- I want to get the value like apple/banana but the select="." is giving values like 1/2/3-->
        <!-- One way is to just put the path you want the value for, but this template I'm calling at many places -->
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="shop/fruits/fruit">
        <xsl:for-each select="$weights-in-kg">
            <xsl:call-template name="some-template-I-have">
                <!-- SOME-PARAMETER-VALUE-HERE -->
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I usually get the node value for the matched template by using `select="."` but this is the first time I have to use the `call-template` inside of a for-loop and I don't know how to proceed? Using `select="."` is giving the value for the element of `weights-in-kg` inside the template `some-template-I-have`.

Please help me get that concept, I think I'm missing some concept here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling a named template does not change the context. The problem you complain of is  caused by your instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$weights-in-kg">
```

This *does* change the context to the `weight` nodes selected by the variable.

If you want to refer to the `fruit` element that *was* the current node before you called the `xsl:for each` instruction, store in a variable - and if necessary, pass it as a parameter to the named template.